# Can't deploy Puppeteer to IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, puppeteer

I'm trying to deploy Puppeteer to IBM Cloud via CF with https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack buildpack, but always getting the following error:

```
/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
(node:131) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
```

My manifest.yml looks like this:

```
applications:
- path: .
  domain: eu-gb.cf.appdomain.cloud
  command: npm start
  name: Name
  host: Name
  memory: 128M
  instances: 1
  disk_quota: 1024M
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
```

Puppeteer initialised like this:

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
  });
```

Any ideas, how could this be resolved?
Thanks.

Comment: What are the commands you used, what is the manifest file, what is the full error message...? Add as much details as possible

Comment: Are you using puppeteer or puppeteer-core?

Comment: @data_henrik I've just put manifest file. The command I'm using to push is:
cf push "Name" -f manifest.yml

Comment: @VidyasagarMachupalli It's puppeteer and not puppeteer-core

Comment: Cloud Foundry apps typically are web apps. I don't see how puppeteer fits in or how you made it into a Cloud Foundry app. Provide more details

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I just created a node.js app with `npm init` command, added Puppeteer via `npm i puppeteer` command, added `index.js` with basic Puppeteer sample and then followed two approaches

**Approach 1:**

1. Here's my `manifest.yml` file with buildpack and other parameters defined.

```
  applications:
    - name: puppeteer-test
      buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
      command: npm start
      disk_quota: 1024MB
      memory: 128MB
      instances: 1
```

2. Also, I have run `npm install` locally creating the node_modules. `cf push` will pick the node_modules folder. *Make sure you have right permissions on the folders*
3. I ran `ibmcloud cf push` instead of `cf push`.

**Approach 2**

1. Don't define anything in the `manifest.yml`. Let Cloud foundry decide the buildpack based on the files.

```
  applications:
    - name: puppeteer-test
```

2. Then run

```
ibmcloud cf push
```

There is a third approach where you define everything in `.yml` files starting from dependencies to buildpacks. You can follow the instructions mentioned in the [post here](https://medium.com/@saikatgupta_42184/running-puppeteer-in-cloud-foundry-or-ubuntu-8dd25d847333)

**Note:** As Henrik mentioned, you won't see anything when you visit the `yourappname.bluemix.net` URL as there is not frontend attached to the node.js app.